# Toggle focus onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form inside a panel. The panel opens and closes when a button is clicked. When the panel is opened [i.e., with the click of the button], I want to focus on the first input text box in the form which is inside the panel. When I close the panel [i.e., again clicking on the same button], I want to loose the focus from that input box.

So, in simple words, I want to toggle the focus on the text input box when the onclick event happens on the button.

I gave the input text box an id and did the following:

```
<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="enter code">
```

Inside the script tag:

```
$('.button-element').click(function(){ $('#code').focus();});
```

This makes the focus on the input text box but I want to remove the focus when I click the button again.

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this snippet (tested on chrome):

```js
var $code = $('#code');
$('.button-element').on('mousedown', function () {
    $(this).data('inputFocused', $code.is(":focus"));
}).click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('inputFocused')) {
        $code.blur();
    } else {
        $code.focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="enter code">
<button class="button-element">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late answer, but here is a solution which adds a new jQuery method.

You can add this to top of your `$.onready`:

```
jQuery.fn.toggleFocus = function(){
  if (this.is(":focus")) {
    this.blur();
  } else {
    this.focus();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$(".button-element").toggleFocus()
```

Comment: Great snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var code = $('#code');
$('.button-element').click(function() {
    if(code.is(":focus")) {
        code.blur();
    } else {
        code.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Clicking button removes input focus in all cases

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code to following

```
var focusInput = true;
$('.button-element').click(function(){ 
    if(focusInput) {
       $('#code').focus();
    } else {
       $('#code').blur();
    }
    focusInput = !focusInput;

});
```

Comment: Doesn't handle case where you click once then set focus on other element then reclick button, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/ksqjnksy/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any HTML,you need to change the code according to your need.

```
  $('.button-element').click(function()
  {  
    if($("#ID-of-panel").is(':visible'))
        $('#code').blur();
    else
         $('#code').focus();
   });
```

Comment: @A.Wolff I have understood it as the button click toggles the panel given.Assuming its like that,i have used it.